# How to pull data from one table into another using a column value as reference

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql-workbench

I am completely new to MySql with absolutely zero experience with databases so forgive me if the question is not phrased exactly right or if I have missed anything out.

I have two tables, the first contains customer information that they (the customer) have entered via a web form, and the second contains address information provided by the post office. Both tables contain a postcode/zip code.

Customer Table (1) [contains 50,000+ records]

| customer_name | customer_address | customer_postcode | new_column1 | new_column2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Fred Bloggs | AnyRoadwitherrors | BH21 7DT | null | null |
| Mary Smith | Sxtreetname Xyz | LE3 5SG | null | null |
| George Brown | 1a Hightreet London | SW21 2EE | null | null |

** The customer table often contains spelling or other errors in the address column and does not contain the town/city but the postcode is always accurate.

Address Table (2) [contains 23,000,000 records]

| postcode | street_address | town_address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SW21 2EE | High Street | London |
| BH21 7DT | Any Road | Bournemouth |
| LE3 5SG | Street Name | Leicester |

**The address table provided by the post office contains accurate information.*

I would like to insert data from Table 2 into Table 1 using the customer_postcode column as a reference.

Customer Table (3)

| customer_name | customer_address | customer_postcode | new_column1 | new_column2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Fred Bloggs | AnyRoadwitherrors | BH21 7DT | Any Road | Bournemouth |
| Mary Smith | Streetname Xyz | LE3 5SG | Street Name | Leicester |
| George Brown | 1 HighStreet London | SW21 2EE | High Street | London |

I've tried various methods using "insert into" and "inner join", all without success and having spent days on stack overflow and google searching for answers I am now stuck and so thought I would ask those who know significantly more than I do for assistance.

Comment: As a PostCode can cover more than one house address what do you plan to do with the house number, house name, etc that you dont seem to have in the post office data

Comment: I already have a separate column for house numbers and names, but these are not needed for this project and will be discarded.  I only need to pull in the correct road name and town.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I got all the column names correct

```
UPDATE customer1 c, postcodes po
SET c.new_col1 = po.street_address,
    c.new_col2 = po.town_address
WHERE c.customer_postcode = po.postcode;
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=421ad19110b26027ceb81cd9d723380d)